# Visual Studio only connects to remote device via WMDC one time

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, windows-ce, wmdc

I have both Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 installed on my main PC dev machine. I had a project that I could connect to a Wince5.0 device and debug via vs08 about 5 months ago. Now the same project will not debug the project, I am getting a "Unable to start debugging" window from VS after the connection is made and the exe deployed.

I can connect to the device, via WMDC. I can see all the files and etc to the remote device. VS will download the application but will just not start debugging. I take the exact same project compile it and run it from VS 2005 and I can debug.

Also what I have found is that if I create a new project from VS2008 it will deploy and debug as long as I do not close VS2008. Once I shut down VS08 and reopen the project the "Unable to start debugging" message will appear on ever deploy.

I've tried everything I can think of and have read on, change security settings, look at registry on the device and etc. It just seems to be some VS2008 issue that just started.

Comment: Don't forget to add an additional blank line between paragraphs or it just jams together into a huge wall of words.

Comment: Is the correct debugger selected in Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Debugger to launch?

Comment: Yes, under 'Debugger to launch:' there is a drop down with only one option "Smart Device Native Debugger".